# How can I access a public domain that is hosted within my local network?

Tags: networking, dns, routing

I have a domain that is running on a server in my local domain. I can access this domain from outside the local LAN. Trying to get to it from within the local LAN of course fails.

Can this be resolved by an A record pointing at the internal address? I also run JIRA and Confluence so the Base URL is a must here as well.